# Beginner sql join query

Tags: sql

I am quite new to sql and I am struggling with creating one query. I have a table Dept_Employee

```
    DeptId    EmployeeId    Salary        JoinDate (DD-MM-YYYY)
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    1            77         8787           11-09-2010
    1            87         9877           12-08-2011
    1            76         9544           08-11-2010
    2            33         9999           12-05-2010
```

And I want to create a new table from this with DeptId and a new column boolean which returns true if all the employees in the same dept have joindate before 01-12-2010 (December 1st) AND their salary should be greater than 8000. So in this case the result should be

```
    DeptId     NewEmployees
    ------------------------
    1            False
    2            True
```

What is the best way to do it? Should I do self join?? Or is there any other way to do it? Please can anyone suggest something...

Jeena.

Comment: since you said you are new, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Also, since you want to create a table that might be duplicating data, you might want to check out Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 5):

SQL `CASE` is your friend for this.

You could do it the following way:

```
 SELECT DeptId, CASE WHEN MIN(Salary) > 8000 AND MAX(JoinDate) <= DATE'2010-12-01' THEN True
                ELSE FALSE
                END AS NewEmployees
   FROM Dept_Employee
  GROUP BY DeptId
```

Note that I assumed that 12 was the month and 01 the day in your question.

Comment: yes 12 is month. I was able to create first part of query but groupby was missing thats why it didn't work. I am gonna try it now. Thank u sooo much @Benoit

Comment: Ok. That works as a charm!! But now I realized that there is one more column for deptName and I want one more check for true or false. that DeptName should be Admin Or IT. I tried to extend the above with DeptName Like condition but I am getting exception  00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression" Any idea why??

Comment: @Jeena: If there is only one possible value of DeptName for each DeptId, then include `DeptName` in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The problem is DeptName can have multiple values but I want to have true if all the deptNames="Admin" and  MIN(Salary) > 8000 AND MAX(JoinDate) <= DATE'2010-12-01' And it does not work by adding DeptName in groupBy

Comment: Use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT deptName) = 1` and `AND MAX(deptName) = 'Admin'`