# Not a group by Exception in sql query

Tags: sql

Actually this question is follow up of my 
[Beginner sql join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812146/beginner-sql-join-query)

Just to make it less confusing I am creating a new one because I don't know if I should update the previous question. So the problem here is with `GROUP BY` function.

I have a table `Dept_Employee`

```
    DeptId    EmployeeId    Salary        JoinDate (DD-MM-YYYY)     DeptName
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            77         8787           11-09-2010                  ADMIN
    1            87         9877           12-08-2010                  ADMIN 
    1            76         9544           08-11-2010                  SUPPORT  
    2            33         9999           12-05-2010                  ADMIN
```

And I want to create a new table from this with `DeptId` and a new boolean column which returns true if all the employees in the same dept have a `joindate` before 01-12-2010 (December 1st) AND their salary should be greater than 8000 and `DeptName="Admin"`.

So in this case the result should be

```
    DeptId     NewEmployees
    ------------------------
    1            False
    2            True
```

I tried something like this

```
   SELECT DeptId, 
     CASE WHEN MIN(Salary) > 8000 AND 
               MAX(JoinDate) <= DATE'2010-12-01' And
               DeptName ="Admin" THEN True
          ELSE FALSE
     END AS NewEmployees
   FROM Dept_Employee
   GROUP BY DeptId
```

But I am getting exception

> *not a GROUP BY expression*

Please can anyone suggest what is the right way to do? Should I create subqueries somehow or what???

Jeena.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DeptID,
        CASE WHEN totals = totalCount THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END NewEmployees
FROM
(
    SELECT  DeptID, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN Salary > 8000 AND JoinDate <= DATE'2010-12-01' AND DeptName = 'ADMIN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totals,
            COUNT(*) totalCount
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP   BY DeptID
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Dept_Employee.DeptId, CASE WHEN OptionDept.DeptId IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS NewEmployees
FROM Dept_Employee
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DeptId
    FROM Dept_Employee
    GROUP BY DeptId
    HAVING MIN(Salary) > 8000 AND MAX(JoinDate) <= DATE'2010-12-01' AND DeptName ="Admin"
) AS OptionDept ON OptionDept.DeptId = Dept_Employee.DeptdId
```

Explanation: you can't refer in select list to fields which isn't participate in Group By clause - because after group by you are working with group and not with separate records, as a workaround - you should use subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

DeptName must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct syntax of your orig query:

```
SELECT deptno 
 , (CASE WHEN MIN(Sal) > 3000 AND MAX(hiredate) <= DATE '2010-12-01' 
     AND deptno = 10 THEN 'True' ELSE 'FALSE'
    END) NewEmployees
 FROM scott.emp
GROUP BY deptno
/
```

This is syntactic example only. Not sure what are you trying to achieve...